# Injecting error logger with structuremap

Tags: logging, structuremap, elmah

I'm using Elmah for logging with a class that looks pretty much like this http://blog.omniaconnect.net/2009/07/30/using-a-static-class-for-logging-exceptions-using-elmah/ , should I inject this static class using structuremap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the class is static, there is nothing to inject. If you wanted to inject the error class, you would need to remove all the static keywords from it.